# Momentum Equation (Navier Stokes System)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I think there is some mistake in the definition in my lecture notes. The notes define the momentum equation by

$\partial _t (\rho u ) + \text{div}_x(\rho u \times u) + \nabla _xp(\rho) + \text{div}_x S(u) = \rho f$

with the velocity $u$, density $\rho$ and pressure $p$. Here

$\text{div}_xS(u) := -\mu \Delta _x u - (\lambda + \mu)\nabla _x \text{div}_xu$,

but later we try to determine the pressure formally by writing

$p(\rho) = -\Delta _x^{-1}\text{div}_x \partial _t(\rho u ) - \Delta _x^{-1}\text{div}_x\text{div}_x (\rho u \times u) + \Delta _x^{-1}\text{div}_x\text{div}_xS + \Delta _x^{-1} \text{div}_x (\rho f).$

Here the sign of the term with the stress tensor $S$ seems to have changed for no reason. Can someone please tell me, which of the two equations is wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign in the first equation is correct, and it appears that there is a sign error in the second equation.  You can remember the sign convention for Navier-Stokes if you remember the heat equation, which reads
$$
\partial_t u = \Delta u.
$$
Then the signs for Navier-Stokes match this: time derivatives and second-order derivatives get the same sign on opposite sides of the equation.  This is what appears in the first equation.